# How to use both ltng:outApp and force:slds in lightning Application

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I have created one lightning application which I'm using in my vf page. To use lightning app in vf page I need to extends **ltng:outApp** but at the same time I also want to use lightning design system.
How can I use both at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do anything, extending `ltng:outApp` will also get you SLDS, as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm):

> Extending from ltng:outApp adds SLDS resources to the page to allow
>   your Lightning components to be styled with the Salesforce Lightning
>   Design System (SLDS). If you don’t want SLDS resources added to the
>   page, extend from ltng:outAppUnstyled instead.

Answer (score -1):

Please go through the code, add the line before commenting lines of the code will resolve your problem

```
<apex:page id="CommercialFinance" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
      <head>
         <title>Commercial Finance</title>
         <apex:includeLightning/> 
    // Help you to have SLDS to your VF page
         <style>
            * {
               margin: 0;
               padding: 0;
            }
         </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="CommercialFinanceDiv"></div>
      <script>
         $Lightning.use("wizard3:AssetFinanceApp", function(){
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                  "wizard3:CommercialFinance",
                  {},
                  "CommercialFinanceDiv",
                  function (cmp){
                  }
            );
         });
      </script>
      </body>
    </apex:page>
    <aura:application description="CommercialFinanceApp" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    // extend ltng:outApp in this fashion
    </aura:application>
```

This might help you out.
Regards,
Akshay